Elementor toggle icon shows on desktop
First off, someone else built the site and I'm just trying to help fix some menu glitches, but for the life of me I can't figure it out. The site is linked here.
The site is running Elementor v3.21.8 & Elementor Pro v3.21.3, WP 6.5.5, active theme is Hello Elementor v3.0.2
Issues:

On desktop, the toggle menu (hamburger) icon flashes underneath the list items as the page is loading. It's like FOUC but only with the toggle icon.
On mobile, the SAME desktop menu (including oddly placed hamburger icon) loads until you scroll down the page. Once you scroll, the menu looks normal, but the open tray is off the left-hand side of the screen and gets cut off.
When logged in to wordpress, everything looks just fine. The issue only shows on the live site.

I've tried:

Clearing browser cache
deactivating all the unnecessary plugins one by one
Elementor->tools->regenerate css
Elementor > Settings > Performance> CSS Print Method > Internal Embedding

